# building pjsip in gnu/linux platform

Tags: c, linux, makefile, autotools, pjsip

I'm trying to build pjsip(www.pjsip.org) in centos 6.2 x86 .

Whenever i issue make dep, it completes without showing an error. after i give make it stops with following error.

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/freeburn/pjsip/trunk/third_party/build/portaudio'
.libportaudio-i686-pc-linux-gnu.depend:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/freeburn/pjsip/trunk/third_party/build/portaudio'
make[2]: *** [libportaudio] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/freeburn/pjsip/trunk/third_party/build/portaudio'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/freeburn/pjsip/trunk/third_party/build'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

in faq page of pjsip its said that if this error happens, then

```
make distclean
```

should solve it. But in my case same error happens after make distclean.
someone at the pjsip mailing list suggested to remove every *.depend file by :

```
$ find . -name "*.depend" -print | xargs rm -f
```

i've done that. but still no luck. although this not a pjsip mailing list, the problem occurs because of .depend files, so i thought someone can shed some light on it so that i get a clue for solving it.

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

After carefully reading the faulty .depend file i've discovered that actually no dependencies were generated at all. they are just name of some targets smashed togather without any dependency list at all. So i guess make dep step is actually buggy to generate correct dependencies. I am trying to find which caused make dep to fail.

Comment: Have a look at the first line of .libportaudio-i686-pc-linux-gnu.depend and find the missing separator make complains about ?

Comment: i think .libportaudio-xyz.depend is produced wrongly. because all the dependencies are stuffed into one line without a line break. i don't know how to fix it. i've tried inserting a space after every file pathname with no luck. i have also reviewed other .depend file in the source tree. all of them has line breaks, and white spaces between to entries.

Comment: Have you tried adding line breaks ?

Comment: see my EDIT, and yes i've tried adding breaks.